# Splitting of Input XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, soa

I want to split the input XML based on a element "ConsolidatedID" and create a new output XML using XSL Transformation Is this possible?

How to achieve this using XSLT in SOA12c

Input XML:

```
<Root>
<Data>
<ConsolidatedID>ONE</ConsolidatedID>
<NewID>First</NewID>
<Amount>100</Amount>
</Data>
<Data>
<ConsolidatedID>ONE</ConsolidatedID>
<NewID>First</NewID>
<Amount>100</Amount>
</Data>
<Data>
<ConsolidatedID>ONE</ConsolidatedID>
<NewID>Second</NewID>
<Amount>200</Amount>
</Data>
<Data>
<ConsolidatedID>TWO</ConsolidatedID>
<NewID>First</NewID>
<Amount>100</Amount>
</Data>
<Data>
<ConsolidatedID>TWO</ConsolidatedID>
<NewID>First</NewID>
<Amount>100</Amount>
</Data>
<ConsolidatedID>TWO</ConsolidatedID>
<NewID>Four</NewID>
<Amount>400</Amount>
</Data>
</Root>
```

O/p expected:

```
<Root>
<Data>
<ConsolidatedID>ONE</ID>
<NewID>First</NewID>
<Amount>100</Amount>
</Data>
<Data>
<ConsolidatedID>ONE</ConsolidatedID>
<NewID>First</NewID>
<Amount>100</Amount>
</Data>
<Data>
<ConsolidatedID>ONE</ConsolidatedID>
<NewID>Second</NewID>
<Amount>200</Amount>
</Data>
</Root>


<Root>
    <Data>
    <ConsolidatedID>TWO</ConsolidatedID>
    <NewID>First</NewID>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    <ConsolidatedID>TWO</ConsolidatedID>
    <NewID>First</NewID>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Data>
    <ConsolidatedID>TWO</ConsolidatedID>
    <NewID>Four</NewID>
    <Amount>400</Amount>
    </Data>
    </Root>
```

Could some one please help me with this issue?

Regards,
Vishnu.

Answer (score 1):

In standard XSLT 2.0 (don't know what SOA supports exactly) you can use

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Data" group-by="ConsolidatedID">
    <xsl:result-document href="{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
      <Root>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </Root>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```